# Three.js - Is there a simple way to change rotation-pivot of Object3D?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Is there a simple way to change rotation-pivot of `THREE.Object3D`?
The default point is the position point of the `Object3d`.

I have group (implemented as `THREE.Object3D`) of objects and I want to rotate all objects together, around `THREE.Vector3` point that can be changed on run-time.

Note: the position of the group cannot be changed.

I have tried this (with **Derte Trdelnik** help), but it doesn't work:

```
someButton.onClick(function () {

    var object = editor.selected;
    if (!object instanceof THREE.Object3D) return;

    var pivot = new THREE.Vector3(100, 0, 0);
    var vectorToPivot = object.position.sub(pivot);
    var moveToPivot = new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(vectorToPivot.x,
                                                          vectorToPivot.y, vectorToPivot.z);
    var rotation = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(Math.PI);
    var inverseMove = new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(-vectorToPivot.x,-vectorToPivot.y, -vectorToPivot.z);

    var matrix = inverseMove.clone().multiply(rotation).multiply(moveToPivot);
    object.applyMatrix(matrix);

    editor.signals.objectChanged.dispatch(object);

});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you dont have to change the position, just create a matrix that does what you want :

```
var vectorToPivot = object.position.sub(pivot);
var moveToPivot = new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(vectorToPivot.x, 
                                                      vectorToPivot.y,vectorToPivot.z);
var rotation = new THREE.Matrix().makeRotationX(Math.PI/2);
var inverseMove = new THREE.Matrix().makeTranslation(-vectorToPivot.x,
                                                     -vectorToPivot.y,-vectorToPivot.z);

var matrix = inverseMove.clone().multiply(rotation).multiply(moveToPivot);
object.applyMatrix(matrix);
```

Comment: did you meant : THREE.Matrix4 in all lines? anyway, its causes position change of the objects under the group or the position of group itself.

Comment: yes i meant to use matrices, it does change the position, i have probably misunderstood your question - you dont want to change the position after rotation? in that case make the pivot vector [0,0,0] and it will rotate around center or if for some reason you have a rotation matrix you want to use - use it and move the group back to its former center

Comment: i'll try to explain better: i have group object (THREE.Object3D) in position {0,0,0}. the group has child - plain object in position {100,0,0}. i want to set rotation pivot for the group object in {100,0,0} - so if i would rotate the group, the plane will rotate around itself. but the group and the plane should stay on their original position. is this clearer? (now the plain rotate around {0,0,0} and not around {100,0,0}

Comment: yes much clearer, you have an object with a child and you want to rotate both of them around their own centers [?]  in that case you have to transform child and the parent separately - first remove the child from the parent `parent.remove(child)` then transform both of them(with 2 different matrices) and link them back together `parent.add(child)`

Comment: OK. I will wxplaim again - forget the last comment. I have group of objects all rotate together. now they all rotate around the position of the group object (object3d). I want them to rotate around some other point (dynamic). In addition , all the objects should keep their original position.